# Android button onclickListener not working on a fragment which has a viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a simple fragment with a ViewPager to display text with a swipe.

I am trying to get OnClick event of a button in this layout shown below but I dont see anything happening, I am new to this and not sure if I am missing any.

Here is the fragment_proposal.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/proposalViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/proposalHeader">                                        
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Here is the resource layout (proposal_swipe.xml) for this ViewPager which will display the text.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/proposalNotesBtn"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/notesText"
        android:text="Save Notes" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/enteredNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/proposalNotesBtn" />
```

Here is my Fragment Class where I try to capture the onclickevent

```
public class ProposalFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

ArrayList<ProposalDetailModel> listProposalDetail;
ViewPager viewPager;
ProposalSwipeAdapter proposalSwipeAdapter;
TextView tv, proposalHeader;
TextView sectionHeader;
Button proposalNotesBtn;
EditText notesText;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public ProposalFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View proposalDetailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_proposal, container, false);
    proposalHeader = (TextView) proposalDetailView.findViewById(R.id.proposalHeader);
    proposalHeader.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments(); //getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    listProposalDetail = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("listDetails");

    View proposalView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.proposal_swipe, container, false);
    proposalNotesBtn = (Button) proposalView.findViewById(R.id.proposalNotesBtn);
    notesText = (EditText) proposalView.findViewById(R.id.notesText);

    proposalNotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("INSIDE CLICK", "INSIDE CLICK");
            new ProposalTask().execute();
        }
    });

    viewPager = (ViewPager) proposalDetailView.findViewById(R.id.proposalViewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ProposalSwipeAdapter(getContext(), listProposalDetail));
    return proposalDetailView;
}
```

I am sure I am missing something. I am returning the view of layout which has the viewpager. When I debugged, I see that proposalNotesBtn is returning an object but onclick of that, I dont see anything happening. Please any help here

here is my ProposalSwipeAdapter class

```
public class ProposalSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> imageResourcess = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ProposalSwipeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProposalDetailModel> list) {
    this.context = context;
    //this.imageResourcess = list;
    for (ProposalDetailModel objectProposal : list
            ) {

        this.imageResourcess.add("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                       PRODUCT/SERVICE \n\n\n\nSERVICE/PRODUCT OFFERED:" + objectProposal.getIntroWhoAreWe() +
                "\n\nTYPE OF CUSTOMERS:" + objectProposal.getAddres() +
                "\n\nWHY WILL THEY BUY IT:" +
                "\n\nPRODUCT PRICE:" +
                "\n\nCOMPETITORS:" +
                "\n\nSERVICE DELIVERY:");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    int index = imageResourcess.indexOf(object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageResourcess.size();
    //return imageResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.proposal_swipe, null);
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalImage);
    //imageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
    TextView tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalText);
    tv.setText(imageResourcess.get(position).toString());
    //tv.setText(imageResources[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    Log.i("PROPOSAL VIEW-->", itemView.toString());
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    //container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
```

Comment: Getting `Log.i("INSIDE CLICK", "INSIDE CLICK");` in log?

Comment: post your code for `ProposalSwipeAdapter`, because here you are just inflating child and assigning click listener on it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I dont see this string in the log

Comment: @RRR Here is the code for ProposalSwipeAdapter. Attached to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code for click listener should be in PagerAdapter `instantiateItem()`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.proposal_swipe, null);
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalImage);
    //imageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
    TextView tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalText);
    tv.setText(imageResourcess.get(position).toString());
    //tv.setText(imageResources[position]);

    Log.i("PROPOSAL VIEW-->", itemView.toString());
    proposalNotesBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.proposalNotesBtn);

    proposalNotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          Log.i("INSIDE CLICK", "INSIDE CLICK");
       }
    });
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: Adding the event to the Adapter solved the issue.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What i see you do wrong is you are inflating two layouts.The proposalDetailView and proposalView and you are returning only one view proposalDetailView to the fragment for its layout. And your button is in proposalView...you are not adding this View to the fragment..add the proposalView as a child of the proposalDetailView or whatever is your purpose..

Comment: Ok That may be the reason but I was not sure how to refer the child to ProposalDetailView

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the button is under another layout?

try removing this line:
android:layout_below="@id/notesText"

Answer (score 0):

move this line `viewPager.setAdapter(new ProposalSwipeAdapter(getContext(), listProposalDetail));`

into onPostExecute of your `ProposalTask()`.